# Exception when I try to pass query result to Dto object "Error mapping types"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, automapper

I am trying to make a basic query to my database with Linq-to-SQL

The query is done correctly, I tried it with LinqPad and it works, the problem (I think so, I'm not an expert) is when trying to pass the result of the query to my `DTO object` `DtoAsset`

I googled it but I can't understand the reason for the error.

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: EntityQueryable`1 -> List`1
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[[<>f__AnonymousType1`3[[System.Int32,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], API, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] ->
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[API.Dtos.DtoAsset, API,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]  --->
> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration
> or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: <>f__AnonymousType1`3 -> DtoAsset <>f__AnonymousType1`3[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] -> API.Dtos.DtoAsset    at
> lambda_method19(Closure , <>f__AnonymousType1`3 , DtoAsset , ResolutionContext )    at lambda_method18(Closure , Object , List`1 ,
> ResolutionContext )    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at lambda_method18(Closure , Object , List`1 , ResolutionContext )
> at API.Controllers.InventoryController.SearhInventory() in
> C:\WebApp\backend\API\Controllers\InventoryControllers.cs:line 47
> at lambda_method6(Closure , Object )

**Endpoint**

```cs
[HttpGet("Search/")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<DtoAsset>>> SearhInventory()
{
    var query =
        from a in context.Assets
        join i in context.Inventories
        on a.inventory_id equals i.inventory_id
        where a.inventory_id == 1
        select new { asset_id = a.asset_id, name = a.name, inventory_id = a.inventory_id };

    await query.ToListAsync();

    List<DtoAsset> dto = mapper.Map<List<DtoAsset>>(query);
    return dto;
}
```

**Mapper**

```cs
namespace API.Map
{
    public class AutoMapper : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapper()
        {
            #region Inventory
            CreateMap<Inventory, DtoInventory>().ReverseMap();
            //Create
            CreateMap<DtoInventoryCreate, Inventory>();
            #endregion

            #region Asset
            CreateMap<Asset, DtoAsset>().ReverseMap();
            //Create
            CreateMap<DtoAssetCreate, Asset>();

            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

**Models**

```cs
public class Asset
{
    public int asset_id { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int inventory_id { get; set; }
    public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
}

public class Inventory
{
    public int inventory_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? created_date { get; set; }
    public List<Asset> Assets { get; set; }

}
```

**DTOs**

```cs
namespace API.Dtos
{
    public class DtoAsset
    {
        public int asset_id { get; set; }
        public int code { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int inventory_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class DtoInventory
    {
        public int inventory_id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public bool status { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
        public List<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Program**

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using API.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader();
                      });
});
//  AutoMapper
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));

// MS SQL Connector start...
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
// ...end

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(
    x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
//      SSL Certifitate = Disable
// app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// CORS!
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is case, when Automaker is not needed. Just `Select` into desired DTO, not in anonymous object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query.ToList() does not return a list of Assets but a list with new anonymous objects with the same properties as the Asset. What you want is:

```
query = ... select new Asset { asset_id = a.asset_id, name = a.name, inventory_id = a.inventory_id };
```

Edit: I just noticed, you also call toList(), but you do not assign the result anywhere.

Comment: let me see if I understand.

Is the use of `await query.ToListAsync();` poorly implemented? Do you mean to tell me that this wants does not return a list? do i have to remove the list? sorry I did not understand you well

Comment: When you write new, you do not say what this new is going to be. So it's an anonymous object, not an Asset. If you write new Asset, then it's going to be one. Try var list = query.ToList(), hover your mouse over it and see what it is in both cases, the one you wrote fist and the one in the answer.